# Unable to find blank lists with Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

In my Dom I got some `li`'s which includes some as.net text boxes as their children.I need to set some of the text-boxes as visible false.When i do this ,the `li` wrapped around this textbox is shown as empty in html.So I desided to remove them and i used this code (and lot more)

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        $('#u li').each(function () {
            if ($(this).html().length == 0) {
                $(this).remove();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

To my surprise No `li` get in to the loop for empty ones.
Note added HTML

```
    <ul id="u">
                   <li class="first-item odd-item">
                       <span id="ContentPlaceHolderDefault_cphContents_ShopConfirmation_2_lblFirstname">Firstname</span>
                        <input type="text" id="ContentPlaceHolderDefault_cphContents_ShopConfirmation_2_txtFirstname" name="ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderDefault$cphContents$ShopConfirmation_2$txtFirstname">
                        <span style="color:Red;visibility:hidden;" id="ContentPlaceHolderDefault_cphContents_ShopConfirmation_2_reqirefieldFirstname">*</span>
                   </li>
                   <li class="odd-item">
                       <span class="m-left" id="ContentPlaceHolderDefault_cphContents_ShopConfirmation_2_lblLastname">Lastname</span>
                        <input type="text" id="ContentPlaceHolderDefault_cphContents_ShopConfirmation_2_txtLastname" name="ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderDefault$cphContents$ShopConfirmation_2$txtLastname">
                       <span style="color:Red;visibility:hidden;" id="ContentPlaceHolderDefault_cphContents_ShopConfirmation_2_reqirefieldLastname">*</span>
                   </li>
                   <li class="third-item odd-item">
                       <span id="ContentPlaceHolderDefault_cphContents_ShopConfirmation_2_lblEmployeenumber">Emloyee Number</span> 
                        <input type="text" id="ContentPlaceHolderDefault_cphContents_ShopConfirmation_2_txtEmployeenumber" name="ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderDefault$cphContents$ShopConfirmation_2$txtEmployeenumber">
                    </li>
                    <li class="odd-item">


                    </li>
                    <li class="odd-item">
                        <span id="ContentPlaceHolderDefault_cphContents_ShopConfirmation_2_lblAddress">Address</span>
                        <select id="ContentPlaceHolderDefault_cphContents_ShopConfirmation_2_dropdownaddress" name="ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderDefault$cphContents$ShopConfirmation_2$dropdownaddress">
    <option value="-----------Select-----------">-----------Select-----------</option>
    <option value="dfddfd">dfddfd</option>
    <option value="gdfgfg">gdfgfg</option>
    <option value="fhgfgfgf">fhgfgfgf</option>

</select>
                    </li>
                    <li class="third-item last-item odd-item">


                    </li>

                  </ul>
```

Comment: Is it `$('#u li')` or a typo to `$('ul li')`...?

Comment: Can we see the generated HTML?

Comment: Are you hiding the text boxes server-side or client-side?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist:I am hiding it from serverside

Comment: @A.V:I have added Full HTML.you can see its  $('#u li')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from the HTML you've edited into the question, there's no content inside of the `<li>` element. However, the `innerHTML` of the element isn't an empty string, it's a string containing some whitespace. Simply trimming the HTML should work:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('#u li').each(function () {
        if ($.trim($(this).html()).length == 0) {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Take a look at [this jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h6fC2/).

Comment: Oh you're right, I misread the HTML in my answer...yeah, whitespace can be a pain, and also even HTML comments count as content...fortunately you don't have to deal with the possibility of comments here.

Comment: I had tried all answers listed here ,out of them the only one worked for me is yours.Thanks for the great help

Comment: Since your non-empty `<li>` elements all have child elements, you could alternatively just check to see if the `<li>` element had any child elements, e.g. `$('#u li').each(function () { if ($(this).children().length==0) { $(this).remove(); } })`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#u li').each(function(){
   if($('input', this).is(':hidden')){
      $(this).remove();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( $(this).is(':empty') ){  // BOOLEAN TRUE / FALSE
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: My vote is now for @Anthony Grist's answer - whitespace seems to be the issue.

I don't think the OP is trying to check for `<input type="hidden">` but rather for `<input>` elements with `style.display` == 'none'.

So, here's a solution for that:

```
$('#u li input').each(function() {
    var display = $(this).css('display');
    if (display=='none') {
        $(this).closest('li').remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: That's not the case based on the HTML in the question.

Comment: He hadn't posted the HTML yet at the time I answered...editing my answer now.

Comment: why are you testing for `display==''` as far as I know that just says it's not set explicitly and since the parent element is visible will result in the testen element being visible as well

Comment: @RuneFS Oops you're right, I had it reversed, `display==''` along with `display=='block'` is what you'd need to test to see if a block-level element *was* being displayed. Answer edited.